# Unique Count - TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

CODE

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (ID INT, AVAIL BIT, FK INT, DT DATETIME);
INSERT INTO #TEMP (ID,AVAIL,FK,DT)
SELECT 1,1,1,GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,0,2,GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1,3,GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,4,GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,0,5,GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,1,6,GETDATE();


CREATE TABLE #FK (FK INT, DT2 DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #FK (FK, DT2)
SELECT 1,NULL
UNION
SELECT 2,DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())
UNION
SELECT 3,DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())
UNION
SELECT 4,NULL
UNION
SELECT 5,NULL
UNION
SELECT 6,DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())
UNION
SELECT 7,DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())


SELECT 
[TotalIds] = COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
,[TotalAvail] = SUM(CASE WHEN [AVAIL] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
,[DTDIFF] = SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,T1.DT,F.DT2))
FROM #TEMP T1 INNER JOIN #FK F
    ON T1.FK = F.FK;

DROP TABLE #TEMP;
DROP TABLE #FK;
```

OUTPUT

```
TotalIds    TotalAvail  DTDIFF
5           4           3
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
TotalIds    TotalAvail  DTDIFF
5           3           3
```

**GOAL:**
I want to get `sum/count of UNIQUE IDs where [AVAIL] = 1.`

I can do that by `COUNT(DISTINCT ID) WHERE [AVAIL] = 1` BUT... I need to do that within this SUM since I'm querying other data within the same query.

```
 Desired output = 3 
(for ID 1, 3, and 5).
```

Updated with Current/Desired output.
Updated with more data.

Comment: show us db schema, sample data, current result and expected result, You only show us first two. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: If the obvious answer doesn't work, you should post the query showing why it won't work...

Comment: what is the difference between `row = 1` and `row = 4`? why you sum one and not the other? You need to include your other data, other wise your `SELECT DISTICT .. WHERE` should work

Comment: We need to see the rest of the query to understand why you have to use `SUM`.  Without this extra info, you are not going to get any useful help.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN avail = 1 THEN unique_id ELSE NULL END)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (ID INT, AVAIL BIT, FK INT, DT DATETIME);
INSERT INTO #TEMP (ID,AVAIL,FK,DT)
SELECT 1,1,1,GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,0,2,GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1,3,GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,4,GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,0,5,GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,1,6,GETDATE();


CREATE TABLE #FK (FK INT, DT2 DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #FK (FK, DT2)
SELECT 1,NULL
UNION
SELECT 2,DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())
UNION
SELECT 3,DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())
UNION
SELECT 4,NULL
UNION
SELECT 5,NULL
UNION
SELECT 6,DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())
UNION
SELECT 7,DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())


SELECT 
[TotalIds] = COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
,[TotalAvail] = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [AVAIL] = 1 THEN ID ELSE NULL END)
,[DTDIFF] = SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,T1.DT,F.DT2))
FROM #TEMP T1 INNER JOIN #FK F
    ON T1.FK = F.FK;


DROP TABLE #TEMP;
DROP TABLE #FK;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could change `UNION` ALL for `UNION` and remove the duplicates

But you mention otherValue, so maybe you need something like this

```
SELECT SUM(otherValue)
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT ID, AVAIL, otherValue
      FROM TEMP
      WHERE [AVAIL] = 1
     ) T
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the  cte result for your further process.

```
;WITH CTE_Temp AS
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) [TotalAvail] 
 FROM  #TEMP
 WHERE [Avail]=1)
 SELECT [TotalAvail]
 FROM CTE_Temp
```